# Плывет верстка col-xs-6 на Iphone, блоки не располагаются в ряд Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, prestashop

Здравствуйте делаю сайт [emotions4u](http://emotions4u.ru/12-buketi-tsvetov)
На ПК и Android все идеально на iphone верстка плывет(первый скрин)
Блоки расположены примерно как в коде ниже. Но на iphone блоки не хотят становится один рядом с другим. второй блок норовит уехать.
Как это по править? Если не знаете ответ подскажите какой ввести запрос в гугле, не могу найти даже предварительное решение

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #111"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #222"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #333"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #444"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #555"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #666"></div>
</div>
```

[image: bags]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уберите height фиксированный

Comment: НЕ помогло, тот же эффект

Answer (score 0):

У вас в одной строке 36 колонок, а должно быть 12. См. [Bootstrap Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid)

Comment: не помогло, iphone на каждой .row делает отступ с лева 1px, и отрисовывает .col-xs-6 в столбик

Comment: Не забыли в head добавить `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`?

Comment: И ещё попробуйте другой браузер вместо Safari.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #111"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #222"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #333"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #444"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #555"></div>
   <div class="col-xs-6" style="height: 50px; background: #666"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: не помогло, iphone не отображает как надо